# react-bootstrap modal not showing up

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a page where I display a table with some data. Upon clicking the table-row, I wish to show a modal with some more details. The row click will first make an API call and then show that data.

I'm able to make the API call and get the data, but not able to show the modal.

Here's the table component. I need to capture the details of the API call into `instanceInfo`.

```
const InstanceList = (props) => {
    const [instanceInfo, setInstanceInfo] = useState(null);
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    const handleModalClose = () => {
        setShowModal(false);
    };

    const getInstanceDetails = (instanceID) => {
        fetch(`${apiURL}/product-details/${instanceID}`, {
            method: 'post',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((instanceDetails) => {
                const details = {};
                // add data I need to details
                .
                .

                setInstanceInfo(details);
                setShowModal(true);

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
 
   return (
      <div>
        <table>
        .
        .
          <tbody>
            {items.map((obj) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={obj.id} onClick={() => getInstanceDetails(obj.id)}>
                                        <td>..</td>
                                        <td>..</td>
                                    </tr>)
                            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
   )
     {showModal && <InstanceDetailsModal show={showModal} onHide={handleModalClose} details={instanceInfo} />}
    </div>
};
```

The modal component:

```
const InstanceDetailsModal = (props) => {
    return (
        <Modal show={props.showModal} onHide={props.handleModalClose} animation={false}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Instance Details</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>{props.details}</Modal.Body>
        </Modal>


        // <>
        //     {alert(JSON.stringify(props.details, null, 4))}
        // </>
    );
};
```

Even when I open the window inspector, I'm not able to see the modal showing up. However, the `alert` that I commented out in the modal component shows up correctly, if I use that.

I also tried setting the `fade` and `animation` props for the modal to `false`, but that did not work either.

I've added only parts of the components, will be happy to add more code if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong prop name in `InstanceDetailsModal` , it should be `show={props.show}` instead of `show={props.showModal}`.

Comment: Ah! This makes complete sense, don't know how I didn't catch that! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in the modal Component!

```
<InstanceDetailsModal show={showModal} onHide={handleModalClose} details={instanceInfo} />
```

you pass [show, onHide, details] as props

```
<Modal show={props.showModal} onHide={props.handleModalClose} animation={false}>
```

Here you're using props.showModal (should be 'props.show'), props.handleModalClose (should be 'props.onHide')